# How to change the TextColor auf ActionBarCompat MenuItem at runtime?

Tags: android, text, menuitem, textcolor, android-actionbar-compat

I need to change the TextColor of the MenuItems in my ActionBarCompat at runtime. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: i did and if i understand correctly it is not possible to change the style at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the question well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the spannable string to change the text of the menu item.
here is the sample code for ur reference.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuId, menu);
SpannableString str = new SpannableString("Menu item text");
str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, str.length(), 0);
menu.getItem(R.id.menuItemId).setTitle(str);
}
```